# Document count mismatch for join field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index named `parent_child` with about 2.5 million documents in it.  The index stores documents of two different entities(`user` and `purchases`) that have a parent-child relationship. i.e. `one user -> many purchases`.

It has a join field named `join` that declares the above relationship.

The total `user` count is **2 million** and the total `purchases` count is **0.5 million**.

When I run the following `has_parent` query for getting all purchases having a `user`,

```
GET parent_child/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "has_parent": {
            "parent_type": "user",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

it returns the correct document count of **500,000**. But the corresponding child query for getting all `users` with a `purchase`

```
GET parent_child/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "has_child": {
            "type": "purchases",
            "query": {
              "match_all": {
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

returns only **170,000** documents which is the wrong count.

Does anyone know why the discrepancy for the `has_child` query is present?

Cluster info: I'm using ElasticSearch version **6.3** on a single node Linux VM.

Comment: You have more users than purchases. Does each purchase belong to a different user or can a user have made multiple purchases? How many parent documents do you expect?

Comment: @Val Each user can have multiple purchases and there are users who have multiple purchases. I had assumed wrongly that the `has_parent` search would return unique counts. Thanks for your comment, it was very helpful.

Comment: Indeed, `has_child` can only return parent documents which actually have at least one child, but not all parent documents which have no children yet, but might in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I had wrongly assumed that `has_parent` would return unique hits, which was the source of the issue. There was no mismatch.